# PHP: fatal error while using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I have file **learn.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); 
include ("learn2.php");
?>
```

**learn2.php** contains

```
<?php 
namespace test {

    function f1() {
        echo "test";
    }

    const X = "1<br>";

}
?>
```

Maybe I'm blind, but why does learn.php  give me following Fatal error?

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first
>   statement in the script in /var/www/html/learn2.php on line 2

Comment: All you need you canread here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: Try to convert your file in UTF8 without BOM if your IDE allow. You can have some white spaces before your namespace declaration?

Comment: Naruto, what do you mean? I do not use <html> or any other tag here. 
Vincent Decaux, I've checked. No white spaces. But in the source code I get <br> before "Fatal error" - I don't know why. Finally I give up, created another file and copied the content - it works. learn2.php was created via CLI in Linux, maybe there was some mistake... I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be just

```
namespace test;
```

No curly brackets.

After the namespace declaration, you should declare a class to hold your function and const property. At least the const doesn't make sense by itself.

Comment: Brackets work fine too (even though they are not recommended).

Comment: Really? I didn't know. However, you still need a class declaration to wrap the constant property.

Comment: Nope, that's incorrect. You can have global constants, and in fact you should use these instead of `define()` whenever possible.

Comment: @amenadiel I'm aware of this, I get fatal error whether I use 
`namespace test;` or `namespace test {}`

Comment: I see, you can declare global constants since PHP 5.3, but are there namespaced constants outside a class scope?

Comment: @amenadiel: Yes. `namespace foo { const bar = 42; }`, outside this namespace you have to `echo foo\bar` to get the value.

Comment: Cool. Just FYI: there was some error while creating the file, I copied the content into new one and it works. Thus, I still don't know what was the reason.